# Trouble installing jdee in Carbon Emacs in Snow Leopard

Tags: emacs, jde

I recently decided to try emacs for java development, so this is the first time I've used emacs. I'm not getting any error on emacs startup, but I don't think jde is installed correctly because I don't see a "jde" menu item when viewing java files. Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot further?

I downloaded and extracted cedet, jde, and elib into the following dir structure:

```
~/.emacs.d/site/cedet/latest
~/.emacs.d/site/jde/latest
~/.emacs.d/stie/elib/latest
```

In each case 'latest' is a symlink to a versioned dir, for example:

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/site/cedet
ls -al
drwxr-xr-x@ 17 dparoulek  staff  578 Dec  4 12:17 cedet-1.0pre6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dparoulek  staff   14 Dec  4 21:41 latest -> cedet-1.0pre6/
```

Here's my .emacs file:

```
; JDE - Java Development Environment

;; Set the debug option to enable a backtrace when a
;; problem occurs.
(setq debug-on-error t)

;; Update the Emacs load-path to include the path to
;; the JDE and its require packages. This code assumes
;; that you have installed the packages in the emacs/site
;; subdirectory of your home directory.
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/site/jde/latest/lisp"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/site/cedet/latest/common"))
(load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/site/cedet/latest/common/cedet.el"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/site/elib/latest"))

(require 'jde)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that emacs writes start-up log messages to a *Messages* buffer. Once I found that, I realized that there are some problems when it tries to load some things defined in my .emacs file.

I was able to get cedet and ecb working successfully but still getting lisp errors when trying to load jde.